# My MacBook's Touch Bar went black, any solutions? Fingerprint works fine

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, keyboard, touch-bar

**How can I fix a Macbook Pro when the Touch Bar doesn't work?**

I have 13 inch 2019 MacBook Pro, and after updating to macOs 10.15.6, the Touch Bar went black. I visit keyboard preferences and saw this [image]

no option for control strip

I tried almost all methods even I erased everything and reinstall the macOS; now I am at Mojaive 10.14.6

**METHODS I TRIED**

i. commands in terminal

```
   sudo pkill TouchBarServer;
      sudo killall “ControlStrip”;
```

But after second command an error shows up

```
     No matching processes were found
```

ii. Erase everything and reInstall macOS from recovery mode

Still the entire TOUCHBAR is black

[image]

Comment: Boot the Mac in diagnostics mode by holding D at startup. That should tell you if the touch bar has bit the dust.

Comment: tried it, but nothing was found

Comment: Then take it to an Apple store or an AASP for servicing.